# JRGraphics2DExporter - How to export report as JPG?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jpeg

I'm searching a method with `JRGraphics2DExporter` to export report as JPG.

Is there any kind of possibility to do that with `JRGraphics2DExporter`?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the `JRGraphics2DExporter`, but this can also be done directly using the [`JasperPrintManager`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrintManager.html)

**Example** of code contemplenting multiple images 1 for every page

```
//Get my print, by filling the report
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map,datasource);

final String extension = "jpg";
final float zoom = 1f;
String fileName = "report";
//one image for every page in my report
int pages = jasperPrint.getPages().size();
for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    try(OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName + "_p" + (i+1) +  "." + extension)){
        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) JasperPrintManager.printPageToImage(jasperPrint, i,zoom);   
        ImageIO.write(image, extension, out); //write image to file
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you like 1 image with all the pages, you should set the `isIgnorePagination="true"` on the jasperReport tag

Answer (score 1):

You could instruct to the exporter in order to dump the report to an image in memory and then save it to disk.

Create the image (set the proper width, height and format):

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Create the exporter, configure it (maybe some other parameters should be set) and export the report:

```
JRGraphics2DExporter exporter = new JRGraphics2DExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRGraphics2DExporterParameter.GRAPHICS_2D, (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics());
exporter.setParameter(JRGraphics2DExporterParameter.ZOOM_RATIO, Float.valueOf(1));

exporter.exportReport();
```

Dump the image to disk:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("image.png"));
```

Comment: Yes you better set JRExporterParameter.PAGE_INDEX to select what page is exported and if ZOOM_RATIO is 1 is nice to get image size for JasperPrint (getPageWidth(),getPageHeight())

Comment: exporter.setParameter is deprecated

Comment: @Novaax You should read [JRAbstractExporter.html.setParameter API doc](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRAbstractExporter.html#setParameter%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter,%20java.lang.Object%29). The setParameter method is replaced by setExporterInput(ExporterInput), setConfiguration(ExporterConfiguration), setConfiguration(ReportExportConfiguration) and setExporterOutput(ExporterOutput)